# Should I fly to an interview if I know I want to accept my current job offer?

Tags: interviewing, travel

I got a decent job offer and I really like the job, location, benefits, etc. I have plans scheduled though to fly to an in person interview in a less desirable location but for a similar job title and different company. It has been a week since I received my current job offer and I am pretty sure that I want to accept it and I think they want a decision soon. I can't guarantee that this interview that I am flying to will lead to a job offer and even if it does it may take some time. Plus I am not sure I want to work in that location anyways. Since flights haven't been scheduled yet for the interview should I back out and accept this offer? Or should I tell the company that offered me a job to give me some more time even though I am very sure I want to accept their offer? I don't want to be rude or waste anyone's time or resources (including mine, the interviewing company, and the job offered company). What should I do?

Comment: duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12565/2322?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a completely personal decision. You have to weigh your interest in the two positions and whether you'd prefer to turn down the interview to accept the first position sooner. There's nothing wrong with postponing acceptance for a week to check out the second company, and there's nothing wrong with accepting the position now and skipping the interview. You have to make the  call based on your personal evaluation of the two positions.